# Can't figure out source of shortcut

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Linux Mint, and I've been trying to set up Shift+Command+3 for a particular task, but it appears that it's already mapped to the "Grouped Window List" panel - it keeps launching app #3 (same is true of the other digit keys - they launch the app corresponding to the number).
Now, Grouped Window List has a separate switch to toggle launching app #N, and it's a shiftless one (Command+N) launches app #3, etc, and that switch is already disabled - Command+n does nothing.

So which application is stealing the shortcut keys? I've looked through every applet as well as Keyboard Settings - nothing is mapped to this combination.